# Starting Android Service on Boot Time

Tags: android, android-service

I'm building a simple service app which runs on boot time. The problem is I want this application is only based on service , there will be no activity. I have BrodcastReceiever class and Service class but I couldn't figure how this service will work on device. I edit the run configuration as nothing. When i add activity it works But as i said this must be just a service application. Why it is not working?

**manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TestService">

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".BootDeviceReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

**BroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class BootDeviceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("testLog","broadCast started");

    if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){
      Intent intentService = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
        intentService.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intentService.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            context.startForegroundService(intentService);
        }else{
            context.startService(intentService);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The log doesn't show up in onReceive function.

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio`. That tag is used for problems/questions related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. When you install your app on a device, your components are all in the "stopped state". They will not be triggered by Android while in the "stopped state". In order to get your components out of this state, the user must, manually, start your app at least once. The only way for the user to start your app is to launch an `Activity`. And the only way for the user to launch an `Activity` is for you to have an `Activity` in your app, and a matching `<activity>` declaration in your manifest, with an `<intent-filter>` containing ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER.

Comment: This helped me a lot thank you so much. I'm going to add Activity components to make it work :)